# How do I start numbering headings with 00 then 01 then 02 etc?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, table-of-contents

I need to find out if heading numbering in a table of contents can start at 00 and how to do this.

Comment: We need more details. What is your operating system? What program are talking about?

Comment: I would say NO as there is no page number 00?

Comment: It's not the page number, it's for a table of contents so for example: 00 Forward 01 Description 02 Operating 03 Appendix etc.

Answer (score 3):

#### How do I number a table of contents as `00`, `01`, etc

See "Customizing Your Numbers" below for general instructions.

In addition for your specific requirement make the following changes to what is shown in the screenshot:

- "Enter formatting for number" should be set to `01`. This will add a leading `0`.
- "Start at" value should be set to `0`. This will start the numbering from `0`.

Your headings will now be numbered `00`, `01` etc and the Table of Contents should reflect this.

You may have to update the Table of Contents to see the changes.

---

#### Customizing Your Numbers

> If you want to change anything about the numbers – for example, you are using the 1.1, 1.2, etc. style but would like the word “Chapter” to display automatically in front of the Heading 1 number, you want to change Arabic numbers to Ordinal, or you want to change the spacing after the numbers, you can.
>
> Click one of your headings, then go back to the Home Ribbon, and in the Paragraph Group click the Multilevel List icon (see screen shot above) and select Define New Multilevel List….  Click the More>> button, then select the relevant list level.
>
> - You can use the Number style for this level: pulldown menu to choose from a various styles, as seen in the screenshot (below the
>     Enter formatting for number: box).
> - In the screenshot, with the Level on the left set at 1, we added the word “Chapter”. Moving to the second level, you can change the
>     period in between the level and sublevel to a dash or anything you
>     want in the Number format box.
> - You can also see that a tab follows the number – you can change it to a space or none. You may have to adjust this if the alignment
>     seems off.
>
>   [image]

Source [Microsoft Word 2010 and 2013 for Dissertations: Automatic Numbering](http://guides.lib.umich.edu/c.php?g=283073&p=1886004)